# A safe Chinese font similar to Facsimile (monospace) font

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts

I am looking for a safe web font for chinese, similar to Facsimile font.

The concept is **old fashion arcade games**.

[image: https://www.type.co.uk/preview/P00012755.gif]

Answer (score 2):

- WenQuanYi Bitmap Song CJK (at 9pt it's just 12x12px, so should be perfect for your needs, especially if you artificially upscale it while preserving hard edges)
- WenQuanYi Unibit
- GNU Unifont

You should be able to convert these to a web format and use on your website quite easily.

As for being web-safe fonts:

- SimSun, NSimSun, SimHei, PMingLiU and MingLiU are only web-safe chinese fonts. In small sizes they might resemble what you need.

But, as far as I'm aware - there is no font containing Chinese characters that will give you pixelized, arcade-alike image right from the box. Your best bet is using one of small-size fonts and artificially up-scale it in post processing (eg. Photoshop) while preserving hard edges for pixelized looks.

I'm afraid there's no easier solution than that. Availability of Chinese fonts is rather poor and if you want to find a font that reminds some specific style - usually it's on the edge of impossibility.

**Fun fact:** in the Chinese market you cannot use any bitmap font that is not authorized by the Chinese government. And I have no idea if these fonts are authorized or not.